# Is each Linear Operator T ,on $ℝ^2$ , non singular?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have this question in front of me that asks me to prove the statement that each Linear operator T on $ℝ^2$ is non singular however, if I take
T: $ℝ^2$ → $ℝ^2$ such that
T(x,y) = (x-y,0) then it is a singular transformation.
Ker(T) = {(x,y) : x=y where x ∈ ℝ, y ∈ ℝ}
What am I missing here?

Comment: I agree with your example. It sounds like either the question has a mistake or you have misunderstood it

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thanks for the reply. I dived into the question and spent 30 minutes and then realised that this is misprint. They forgot to print " following " before linear operator.

Comment: I'm glad to hear you figured out the issue

Comment: The linear operator $T=0$ is singular.

Comment: @copper.hat I did not get what you're implying. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Varun The zero operator is singular, so the statement cannot hold.

Comment: @copper.hat I see. Got it. Thanks a lot